# cakePHP3: Change Entity membername before render

Tags: entity, cakephp-3.0

Is there a elegant way to change an entity membername before it is passed to a view? In my example I have an entity product. My product has a member application_id. I output it to json. Now my Frontend Developer would like to recieve this value as applicationId (no underscore).

As I'm returning a rather complex structure with objects, containing other objects and so on, I won't like to iterate over the whole resultset and change membernames in a loop. So I looked into the entity and hoped to find something like a $_map where I could map membernames to custom names, but I didn't find anything.

Is there a way to do that without using a loop in beforeRender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**manual**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#converting-to-arrays-json) says

> When converting an entity to an JSON the virtual & hidden field lists
>   are applied. Entities are recursively converted to JSON as well. This
>   means that if you eager loaded entities and their associations CakePHP
>   will correctly handle converting the associated data into the correct
>   format.

So you can create a virtual property in your Entoty this way

```
protected $_virtual = ['ApplicationId'];

protected function _getapplicationId()
{
    return $this->application_id;
}
```

seems a little bit against cake naming conventions but it works

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought far enough. I still have to add the application_id to $_hidden to remove it from the output, but thats ok.  Funny thing though, when trying to access $this->application_id in _getapplicationId() it is null, athough XDebug shows me the correct value. I had to change _getapplicationId() to _getapplicationid() then it is working. I guess this is because of some internals with the Inflector which might think getapplicationId tries to get the actual value application_id.